# Solr 4 - Indexing posted text file

Tags: java, solr, solr4

I'm trying to create a field called "sku" - which is indexed with the following analyzer:

```
<fieldType name="sku" class="solr.TextField">
   <analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="(SKU|Part(\sNumber)?):?\s(\[0-9-\]+)" group="3"/>
</analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

This is from reading the documentation here http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer

I already have a Java program that is posting to the solr server succesfully, however it is not grabbing the sku out of any files, and indexing them. Here is my Java code:

```
ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest(
                "/update/extract");
        up.addFile(arg0, arg0.getName());

        up.setParam("literal.id", arg0.getName());
        up.setParam("uprefix", "attr_");
        up.setParam("fmap.content", "attr_content");

        up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);

        server.request(up);
```

Any help appreciated.

I understand I can parse the text files myself and extract the SKU and post them in the parameters to the server, but I thought Solr could do this for me?

Comment: Do your SKU numbers look like what the pattern is meant to capture?  That is: Start with "SKU" or "Part", optional word " Number", optional colon, mandatory(!) space, one or more numbers and hyphens (and nothing else) to be captured.  Note, I believe that will also be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what is going on, because there is a several steps in the middle.

For example, what's your schema.xml definition. Is it definitely using **sku** as its type (and not say string). Then, what's the field name (attr_sku?) and does the extract handler mapping actually maps to it properly? The extract handler usually sends metadata as individual fields and then all file content as one big long field. Is sku somewhere in metadata?

I would do a copyField into something non-processing and see whether the content actually makes it into Solr field. Then, I would start troubleshooting the regex itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alexandre. I have used a copyField as you suggested to see if the content makes it into the solr field. Which it does. I don't see anything wrong with the regex, or the sample data as I coppied it directly from the Lucene docs page (linked in original post) and it looks correct to me.

Nevertheless I have managed to achieve what I wanted (in a different manner, with different tokenizers). Thanks for setting me on the right track debugging this.